# Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file to the project?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, android-studio

I keep getting this error when tried to initialize my firebase on flutter iOS application.

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file to the project?
```

Even if I have added the `GoogleService-Info.plist` into my Runner folder using Xcode!!

my code in main.dart is:

[main.dart code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjp72.png)

and my console keep showing this:

[my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avjwe.png)

And here is my iOS Runner folder after adding GoogleService-info.plist file:

[iOS Runner folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92kiM.png)

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, images and links are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question.

Comment: Clearly follow these steps as mentionend in https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/ios/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your file extension. Do change the extension of `GoogleService-info.xml` file to `GoogleService-info.plist`, and then add it to your project's `Runner` folder using xCode.

Comment: if still not fix this issue then remove the Podfile + podfile.lock and again run the app on xcode

Answer (score 3):

I can see that in the folder tree image you added to the question, you have added the `GoogleService-Info` file as an `xml` file. It should be a property list file, that is, a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. Review the source of your file and its extension and see if that works.